# I can not address entry float in tkinter and use it

Tags: python, tkinter

I would be glad if anyone could help me achieve my task regarding generating a drawing in dxf. Even though everything goes fine without gui, I have difficulty in getting the entry from the tkinter entry field. 
I am using a = self.a.get() but seems that it does not take the number from entry. 
Here is what I did:

```
from tkinter import *
import dxfwrite
from dxfwrite import DXFEngine as dxf

class GUI(Frame):

  def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.grid()
    self.fnameLabel = Label(master, text="height: ")
    self.fnameLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
    self.a = DoubleVar()
    self.a = Entry(master)
    self.a.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
    self.submitButton = Button(master, command=self.buttonClick, 
    text="generate drawing")
    self.submitButton.grid()

  def buttonClick(self):
    a = self.a.get()
    drawing = dxf.drawing('test111.dxf')
    drawing.add_layer('lines')

    a = float()
    b = float()
    b = 0.05
    while True:
      drawing.add(dxf.line((0.03, b), (a, b), color=40, layer='lines'))
      b += 0.15
      if b >= a + 1:
        break

    drawing.save()

if __name__ == "__main__":  
  guiFrame = GUI()
  guiFrame.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've got too much unrelated code in your question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with emphasis on "minimal". You'll get more and possibly better answers quicker that way.

Comment: thank you @martineau. I will try to better ask a question but, since I am a beginner, I hope not but it might take some time unfortunately :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When yot convert a string to a float you have to tell the function what to convert. If you don't supply a parameter the float function will return 0.0.

```
a = float()  # Returns 0.0
a = float(a) # Returns the float representation of a
```

Comment: Thank you very much @figbeam. I really appreciate your support. Many thanks again.